# Importing issues in Big Query while analysis

Tags: csv, google-bigquery

I choosed Cyclistic case study and bump into some problems during data importing to Big Query.

Firstly, I downloaded .csv files and tried to import them from local folder, but files are too heavy (more than 100M).

Then I archived files and tried again, but got an Error: Bad character (ASCII 0) encountered.

Tried to change unicode of files but without output.

Tried to load files from Google Drive, but again I received error message that my URL didn't consist [file=id]. I thought it's problem in URL, but after I tried small Excel spreadsheet from Drive and it worked. Maybe problem is in csv format?

Also tried Google Storage and Amazon S3 but both need my credit card information.

Can you help me please?

I'm new one to programming, so please explain wide